# Delete keywords from Excel File using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of keywords that I want to find and delete the entire row in a spreadsheet. The goal is for it to find these key words, replace them with "#N/A", and then delete those rows associated.

Right now I get an error on the second to last line of code that states, "Run-time error '1004': No cells were found." This makes sense as I realized I need to find the string "#N/A" not an error.

I'm struggling to come up with a way to delete the rows associated with the "#N/A" string.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Delete_EEE()

Dim Wrds As Variant, Gwrd As String
Dim i As Long

Gwrd = "Jans"
Wrds = Array("ohm", "resistor", "MCKT", "micro", "inductor")

Range("G:G").Replace Gwrd, "#N/A", xlPart, , False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For i = LBound(Wrds) To UBound(Wrds)
    Range("E:E").Replace Wrds(i), "#N/A", xlPart, , False
    Range("I:I").Replace Wrds(i), "#N/A", xlPart, , False
Next i

Range("E:I").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just loop through all rows, if text exists `EntireRow.Delete`

Answer (score 1):

You need to start with the last row with data and work you way up when you want to delete rows. And below you will find a piece of code to check if any value in your array is in the source string, which string could be the content of a cell.

```
'********************************************************************************************************************
' To check if any word from an array is within the source string
' Duplicate blanks are removed and strings put in lower case for the validation
' Returns False if there was an error or no item was found
'********************************************************************************************************************
Public Function isFromArrInSentence(ByVal strSource As Variant, ByVal wordsArray As Variant) As Boolean
Dim tmpBool As Boolean, x As Long

tmpBool = False
If VarType(strSource) = vbString And IsArray(wordsArray) Then
    strSource = LCase(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(strSource))
    If Len(strSource) > 0 Then
        If Not isEmpty(wordsArray) Then
            For x = LBound(wordsArray) To UBound(wordsArray)
                If InStr(1, strSource, LCase(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(wordsArray(x)))) > 0 Then
                    tmpBool = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next x
        End If
    End If
End If
isFromArrInSentence = tmpBool

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column contains your value exactly as it appears, you do not need to loop at all. Just filter by your values, and delete the visible range

```
Option Explicit

Sub iDelete()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim Arr, LR As Long, DeleteMe As Range
Arr = Array("ohm", "resistor", "MCKT", "micro", "inductor")

LR = ws.Range("G" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Range("G:G").AutoFilter 1, Arr, xlFilterValues

Set DeleteMe = ws.Range("G2:G" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

If Not DeleteMe Is Nothing Then
    DeleteMe.EntireRow.Delete
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting I will give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a simpler method:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row

For CurRow = LastRow to 1 Step -1
    GVal = Cells(CurRow, 7).Value 'column G
    Select Case True
        Case GVal Like "*ohm*", GVal Like "*resistor*", GVal Like "*MCKT*", GVal Like "*micro*", GVal Like "*inductor*"
            Cells(CurRow, 7).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End Select
    EVal = Cells(CurRow, 5).Value 'column E
    Select Case True
        Case EVal Like "*ohm*", EVal Like "*resistor*", EVal Like "*MCKT*", EVal Like "*micro*", EVal Like "*inductor*"
            Cells(CurRow, 7).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End Select
    IVal = Cells(CurRow, 9).Value 'column I
    Select Case True
        Case IVal Like "*ohm*", IVal Like "*resistor*", IVal Like "*MCKT*", IVal Like "*micro*", IVal Like "*inductor*"
            Cells(CurRow, 7).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
    End Select
Next CurRow
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this shortly!

Comment: @Christmas007 I get a "Type mismatch" error on the fourth line of code starting with "Case"

Comment: Also keep in mind that the keywords might be part of a longer string. Hence why I used xlPart in my original code.

Comment: @CC268 I fixed the issue by adding commas in the case rather than OR... I'm working on a solution for your "part of larger string" issue...

Comment: @CC268I added a `like` code to handle longer strings that should work

Comment: I appreciate the help. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to be doing anything. That said, I got some help on making my other code work and it appears to be finally working.